# How to remove all rows in a data frame before a certain timestamp?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, timestamp

I have a dataeframe and the first column is "date" in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I want to be able to remove all rows in the data frame that are prior to a certain date and time?

So for example, if below I want to remove all rows before 2021-07-19 11:30:30. How do I go about this?

The time I want to filer is also saved to the environment as a variable known as "startdatetime"

```
date
2021-07-19 11:30:00
2021-07-19 11:30:15
2021-07-19 11:30:30
2021-07-19 11:30:45
2021-07-19 11:31:00
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
#  filter(date >= as.POSIXct("2021-07-19 11:30:30"))
  filter(date >= "2021-07-19 11:30:30") # thanks to ThomasIsCoding: as.POSIXct isn't necessary
```

which returns

```r
                 date
1 2021-07-19 11:30:30
2 2021-07-19 11:30:45
3 2021-07-19 11:31:00
```

Comment: I think it should work even without `as.POSIXct` :)

Comment: You are right! Didn't know that `as.POSICxt` wasn't necessary.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working and the dataframe in my environment still contains all rows.

Comment: @James (1) Could you please provide your data as `dput(head(YourData))`? Edit your question and put the data in there. (2) Your data.frame in your enviroment isn't modified unless you assign the code shown to the dataframe. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the package `lubridate` together with `dplyr`. `lubridate` is designed to make operations with date and time.

Reproducing your example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dates <- c("2021-07-19 11:30:00","2021-07-19 11:30:15","2021-07-19 11:30:30",
           "2021-07-19 11:30:45","2021-07-19 11:31:00")

#coerce string to Date and Time
dates <- ymd_hms(dates) #which means year, month, day, hour, minute and second

df <- data.frame(date = dates)

df %>% filter(date >= ymd_hms("2021-07-19 11:30:30"))
```